# How to get CngKey in web application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, encryption, passwords

I want to access a named key in an ASP.NET MVC application but i am not able to access it.

I create a key using powershell. please find below the code for that.

```
 #Create Cng Key Parameter and set its properties
    [System.Security.Cryptography.CngKeyCreationParameters] $cngKeyParameter =  [System.Security.Cryptography.CngKeyCreationParameters]::new()
    $cngKeyParameter.KeyUsage = [System.Security.Cryptography.CngKeyUsages]::AllUsages
    $cngKeyParameter.ExportPolicy = [System.Security.Cryptography.CngExportPolicies]::AllowPlaintextExport

    $cngKeyParameter.Provider = [System.Security.Cryptography.CngProvider]::MicrosoftSoftwareKeyStorageProvider
    $cngKeyParameter.UIPolicy = [System.Security.Cryptography.CngUIPolicy]::new([System.Security.Cryptography.CngUIProtectionLevels]::None)
    $cngKeyParameter.KeyCreationOptions = [System.Security.Cryptography.CngKeyCreationOptions]::MachineKey

    #Create Cng Property for Length, set its value and add it to Cng Key Parameter
    [System.Security.Cryptography.CngProperty] $cngProperty = [System.Security.Cryptography.CngProperty]::new($cngPropertyName, [System.BitConverter]::GetBytes(2048), [System.Security.Cryptography.CngPropertyOptions]::None)
    $cngKeyParameter.Parameters.Add($cngProperty)

    #Create Cng Key for given $keyName using Rsa Algorithm
    [System.Security.Cryptography.CngKey] $key = [System.Security.Cryptography.CngKey]::Create([System.Security.Cryptography.CngAlgorithm]::Rsa, "ExampleKeyName", $cngKeyParameter)

    Write-Output "CNG Key : ExampleKeyName - Created"
```

The key gets created successfully but the same key is not getting accessed in web application using below code.

```
CngKey.Exists("ExampleKeyName")
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CngKey.Exists("ExampleKeyName")` tries to find user-level key, and your powershell script creates machine-level key. So you need to check with:

```
CngKey.Exists(
   "ExampleKeyName",
   CngProvider.MicrosoftSoftwareKeyStorageProvider, 
   CngKeyOpenOptions.MachineKey
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. yes it works but i had to add "<machineName>\Users" in the security for the newly created key to give access rights and then the code is able to access this key in a web application. What is happening? is it a genuine behaviour. Maybe i need to give access rights permissions to this key via powershell via creating. how can i do that?

Comment: @RonnieKapoor Hi Ronnie. I'm having the same trouble. How did you manage to assign permissions to the machine key?